# Mysql DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) MYSQL ERROR

Tags: jquery, mysql, database

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%W') as day, DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%d') as dat, DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%M') as mon, created_date as dated, SUM(price) AS amount FROM `order_invoice` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND  NOW()  GROUP BY YEAR(created_date) ORDER BY created_date DESC
```

I am getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND  NOW()  GROUP BY YEAR(created_date' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You did mention column name in where clause. Mention WHERE with column name before BETWEEN
like

```
SELECT 
 DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%W') as day, 
 DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%d') as dat, 
 DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%M') as mon,
 created_date as dated, SUM(price) AS amount
FROM `order_invoice` 
WHERE created_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND  NOW()
GROUP BY YEAR(created_date) 
ORDER BY created_date DESC
```

Comment: did you run the query which I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

If created_date is a date field (with no time informations) I would use this:

```
SELECT ... FROM order_invoice
WHERE created_date >= current_date() - INTERVAL 365 DAY
      AND created_date <= current_date()
```

(or you might want to use `>` instead of `>=`)

However I cannot fully understand what you are trying to return from your query, since you are you GROUPING by Year(created_date) and selecting non aggregated columns, like created_date.